# access syntax error in FROM

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I need to do either a `UNION ALL` or an `OUTER JOIN` to link two tables. I thought I had the syntax fine given that I used the same format from microsoft website (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/combine-the-results-of-several-select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-HA010341541.aspx). However, I repeatedly get the message which states; "Syntax Error in FROM clause".

`SummaryID`,.. are all fields and unitcostdata... and Tax are Tables.

My code is

```
SELECT SummaryID, Component, Element, CapitalCost,Subsystem,SourceID
FROM unitcostdata6-4-2013
UNION ALL
SELECT SummaryID, TaxSecond, TaxThird, TaxFourth, SourceID
FROM Tax;
```

---

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is because of your table named `unitcostdata6-4-2013`. Any tables or columns with special characters need to be escaped using square brackets so you need square brackets around your table with the dashes:

```
SELECT SummaryID, Component, Element, CapitalCost,Subsystem,SourceID
FROM [unitcostdata6-4-2013]
UNION ALL
SELECT SummaryID, TaxSecond, TaxThird, TaxFourth, SourceID
FROM Tax;
```

Note, when you are using a UNION query the number of columns must be the same between the first and second query and the datatyps must be the same. You will need to determine if the datatypes are the same if not, then you will have to cast them to the same.  Also you could add a new column in the second query to have an equal number of columns:

```
SELECT SummaryID, Component, Element, CapitalCost,Subsystem,SourceID
FROM [unitcostdata6-4-2013]
UNION ALL
SELECT SummaryID, TaxSecond, TaxThird, TaxFourth, null, SourceID
FROM Tax;
```

Without seeing your data or the desired result, you might be able to JOIN the tables on `SummaryId` and `SourceId`:

```
SELECT u.SummaryID, u.Component, u.Element, 
    u.CapitalCost,u.Subsystem,u.SourceID, 
    t.TaxSecond, t.TaxThird, t.TaxFourth
FROM [unitcostdata6-4-2013] as u
LEFT JOIN Tax as t
    on u.SourceId = t.SourceId
    and u.SummaryId = t.SummaryId
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you have dashes or other characters in your table name you will get a syntax error unless enclosed in brackets (same for columns).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want a [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx); think of UNIONS as making two tables one - and they must have the same column count and data. Just guessing from your fields you want something like this [OUTER JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), that is, if you don't want any data eliminated in either table by the JOIN.

```
SELECT ucd.*, Tax.*
FROM [unitcostdata6-4-2013] ucd
LEFT JOIN Tax on ucd.SummaryID = Tax.SummaryID and ucd.SourceID = Tax.SourceID
```

Comment: This isn't about what he wants. This is about a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, but you don't explain why the query has an error nor do you correct the error. The error is because his table name has special characters and he doesn't enclose the table in brackets. Your query will still give the same error. You make a couple of fair suggestions / assumptions, it is just not what the question is about.

Comment: I am pretty sure MS Access does not support a FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: OK I'll agree but if you just fixed the syntax error with the square brackets - and I did miss that - there would still be an error from mismatched UNION. And, I bet my answer is what he's trying to accomplish.  And you're probably right about the FULL OUTER JOIN I'm a T-SQL guy.  bluefeet's accepted answer is correct

Comment: @user210757 If you see my answer, I expanded on all of the issues with the query.

Comment: @user210757 If you correct your answer with the brackets I'll eat my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the same number of columns in each SELECT statement. The first has 6 and the second has 5. Make sure they are the same datatypes, too.